# Check if data exists before posting into the database in yii2

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

I am trying to check if a book is already in the db to avoid duplication. The code below is popping up for both existing and the one not in the database.

```
public function actionCreate($book_id = 'book_id')
{
$checkmodel = Books::find()->where(['book_id' => $book_id])->one();

if ($checkmodel) {
    Yii::$app->session->setFlash('error', 'The book has been borrowed, Please look for another one.');

    return $this->redirect(Yii::$app->request->referrer);
}

$model = new Books();

if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $checkmodel->save()) {
    Yii::$app->session->setFlash('Success','You have successfully borrowed the book');
    return $this->redirect(['view' => 'book_id', $model->book_id]);

}

return $this->render('create', [
    'model' => $model,
]);
```

}

Comment: post your model Code. 

add unique validation to your Books model. 
Example:
 [[book_id'], 'unique', 'targetAttribute' => ['book_id'], 'message' => 'The book has been borrowed, Please look for another one']

Comment: It looks like you are trying to save `$checkmodel` instead of the new `$model`. You've probably wanted to do `if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {`

Answer (score 0):

You could avoid the check adding a proper validation rule  in you model 
anyway for your code you shou,d try checking  for not null $checkmodel

```
    if (!is_null($checkmodel) {
        Yii::$app->session->setFlash('error', 'The book has been borrowed, Please look for another one.');

        return $this->redirect(Yii::$app->request->referrer);
    }
```

https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-validators-uniquevalidator
https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/input-validation

Answer (score -1):

```
public function actionCreate($book_id = 'book_id')
{   
    $model = new Books();
    // check if post request
    if ( $model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) ) {
        // check if book_id exists in table
        if ( ! Books::find()->where(['book_id' => $book_id])->one() ) {
            // save new record to model
            if ( ! $model->save() ) {
                // set error message and redirect to 'create' page
                Yii::$app->session->setFlash('Error','There was some error in processing your request');
                return $this->redirect(Yii::$app->request->referrer);
            } 
            // if model is saved successfully, redirect to 'view' page
            Yii::$app->session->setFlash('Success','You have successfully borrowed the book');
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'book_id' => $model->book_id]);
        } else {
            // if book_id exist in table, show error message
            Yii::$app->session->setFlash('error', 'The book has been borrowed, Please look for another one.');
            return $this->redirect(Yii::$app->request->referrer);
        }
    }

    return $this->render('create', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);
}
```

It's always better to check "false" condition in if statements than true. Helps us write cleaner code. 
Also there was a syntax error in your redirect to view statement

Comment: No, it's not always better. For example in this case you would redirect user when the form is not valid. That means you would lose the post data and you won't be able to fill the form with data that user entered to let him fix it. Also you wouldn't be able to mark the field that didn't pass the validation.